# countTokens() method misbehave when using directly in loop

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

countTokens() method returns 3 instead of 5 when i am using in for loop.

```html
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String s = "foo1,foo2,foo3,foo4,foo5";
  StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
  System.out.println(tokenizer.countTokens()); // countTokens() return 5
  for (int i = 0; i < tokenizer.countTokens(); i++) // countTokens() return 3
  {
   System.out.println(tokenizer.nextElement());
  }

 }
```

**OUTPUT**

```html
5
foo1
foo2
foo3
```

can anyone let me know the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is becaus when you use

```
tokenizer.nextElement()
```

There are one token less, in this case, each use ofi it, reduce the element counted by

```
tokenizer.countTokens()
```

try that:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < tokenizer.countTokens(); i++) 
    {
        System.out.println(tokenizer.countTokens());
        System.out.println(tokenizer.nextElement());
    }
```

for see it, and that:

```
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        System.out.println(tokenizer.nextElement());
    }
```

for look all the elements correctly.

Regards,